# To run python script at boot time

Tags: python-2.7, debian, raspberry-pi, text-to-speech, raspbian

How to execute/run python script when raspian os(debian+raspberry) boots?
My script has code to convert image to audio..I always executed this script using linux terminal in my raspberry pi..,but now I am struck here..!

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](http://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/rc-local.md):

> In order to have a command or program run when the Pi boots, you can
>   add commands to the rc.local file.

**Update wrt comment:**

1. "I tried, but it did not work" does not work as a description of a problem, just as an answer like "I tried, and it worked" wouldn't help you any.
2. Given the authority of the docs, it stands to reason that you did something wrong. So before looking for alternatives you should see to get it right.
3. Prominent hit for google "rc.local example" is ["scripts - Why doesn't rc.local run all my commands, and ..."](https://askubuntu.com/a/243083); this gives you a checklist for trouble shooting.

Comment: Horner:I tried it but not working, do u have any alternative?

Comment: There are a variety of issues you could be running into.  Permissions and assumptions about the current path are the most common. Google for redirecting your stdout and stderr to a file. You can also defer startup with the at command.

Answer (score 1):

taken from the [Raspberry Pi website](http://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/rc-local.md):

"In order to have a command or program run when the Pi boots, you can add commands to the `rc.local` file. This is especially useful if you want to be able to plug your Pi in to power headless, and have it run a program without configuration or a manual start.

On your Pi, edit the file /etc/rc.local using the editor of your choice. You must edit with root, for example:

```
sudo vim /etc/rc.local
```

Add commands below the comment, but leave the line exit 0 at the end, then save the file and exit."

check out the above link for more info (i'd recommend reading the infinite loop warning)